# Ошибка System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Incorrect syntax near '<'."

Tags: c#, dapper

```
using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   db.Insert(new { Name = text.Text, Level = 1, Type = "item" });// System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Incorrect syntax near '<'."
}
```

В чем ошибка?
И как ее исправить?
Использую Dapper.Contrib(ORM)

Comment: А что в `text.Text`, интересно?

Comment: @ CrazyElf  там просто текст который я ввел, text это TextBox WPF.

Comment: Я вообще не очень понимаю, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Аналог какой команды SQL вы таким образом выполняете? Вы ведь пытаетесь делать INSERT не в таблицу, а в саму базу. Я не очень понимаю, как это работает.

Comment: Какую библиотеку (ORM) вы используете? Откуда этот метод `Insert`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Dapper

Comment: Dapper сам по себе не имеет метода Insert. Ещё раз: какую **именно** библиотеку вы используете? Dapper.Contrib? DapperExtensions?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Dapper.Contrib

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать таблицу, в которую пытаетесь добавить анонимный тип

```
using (IDbConnection db  = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     var entity = new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" };
     var id = db.Insert("Customer", entity);
}
```

Comment: Да, вот непонятно, что у него за insert без указания таблицы.

Comment: @motpfofs Неработает.

Comment: @antonkovalskyi - В программировании нет такого понятия: "не работает". Есть конкретная ошибка с чётким описанием.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Нет такой перегрузки функции INSERT которая может принимать такие параметры.